# How develop modular flutter app to install or uninstall within the app itself

Tags: dart, flutter

We are developing an app with flutter framework. Want to know how can we achieve the following functionality.

1. Base app will have minimal features
2. App should list the available modules to add to the existing app.
3. User should be able to add these (either with in-app purchasing or free)
4. User should also be able to disable/uninstall these modules.

I read about packages and plugins. I felt that they are to be included at development time in pubspec.yaml. But I want to add these modules from an installed app at runtime.

Comment: The more conventional approach is to ship everything and enable/disable functionality as required.

Answer (score 0):

What I can think off right now is to use Android [AIDL](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) to create an assistant apk. Then you can sell it on the App Store.

A short tutorial is available [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/aidl-for-sharing-functionality-between-android-apps/).

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how to get this to work on ios, though.